# How does the size of the set $A(R) = \{(a,b) \; | \; a,b \in N \times N, \; \gcd(a,b) = 1, \; a^2 + b^2 \leq R^2\}$ grow?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, divisibility

How does the size of the set 
$$A(R) = \{(a,b) \; | \; a,b \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}, \; \gcd(a,b) = 1, \; a^2 + b^2 \leq R^2\}$$
grow as a function of $R$?

My try: It's clear that $|A(R)| \leq \pi R^2$ (ish). Since $\mathbb{Z}_R \times \{1\} \subset A(R)$ we can also say $A(R) \geq R$ (ish). I think we can write a formula similar to
$$|A(R)| = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \leq R} \phi(\lfloor \sqrt{k^2-R^2} \rfloor),$$
but I'm pretty sure the above is wrong. Even if it was correct, I don't have any idea how to estimate it.

It also occurs to me that if $F(n)$ is the number of ways to represent $n=a^2+b^2$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then 
$$A(R) = \sum_{k \leq R^2} F(k).$$
If I recall $F(n)$ is exactly known. I think 
$$F \left(a^2 \prod_{i=1}^m q_i \prod_{i=1}^n p_i \right) = 2^n$$
where $n/a^2$ is square free, $q_i = 3 \mod 4$ and $p_i = 1 \mod 4$. It seems this might be difficult to work with.

Comment: Let $B(R) = \{ (a,b)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} : a^2 + b^2\leqslant R^2\}$. Can you express the size of $A(R)$ in terms of the sizes of some $B(r)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Good question! In other words, can we relate $A(R)$ to the Gauss circle problem, but in this case, I don't care about second order terms.

Comment: If you only want the leading term, it's pretty quick then. Yes, there is a relation between the $A(R)$ and $B(r)$. Generalised Möbius inversion is something to look at.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in the leading term. Do you care to write an answer?

Comment: Sure, give me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we disregard the coprimality constraint for a moment, we look at the sets

$$B(R) = \{(a,b) \in\mathbb{N}^2 : a^2 + b^2 \leqslant R^2\}.$$

It is easy to see that

$$\lvert B(R)\rvert = \frac{\pi}{4} R^2 + O(R).\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, each pair $(a,b)$ with $a^2 + b^2$ can uniquely be written as $d\cdot (\alpha,\beta)$ with $\gcd(\alpha,\beta) = 1$, so we have

$$\lvert B(R)\rvert = \sum_{d=1}^R \left\lvert A\biggl( \frac{R}{d}\biggr)\right\rvert.\tag{2}$$

By [generalised Möbius inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations), $(2)$ is equivalent to

$$\lvert A(R)\rvert = \sum_{d=1}^R \mu(d)\left\lvert B\biggl(\frac{R}{d}\biggr)\right\rvert.\tag{3}$$

where $\mu$ is the Möbius function. If $R$ is constrained to be an integer, we must replace $\frac{R}{d}$ with $\left\lfloor\frac{R}{d}\right\rfloor$ in $(2)$ and $(3)$, and below.

Inserting $(1)$ into $(3)$, we obtain

$$\lvert A(R)\rvert = \sum_{d=1}^R \mu(d) \left(\biggl( \frac{R}{d}\biggr)^2 + O\biggl(\frac{R}{d}\biggr)\right),\tag{4}$$

and as $\left\lvert \sum\limits_{d=1}^R\frac{\mu(d)}{d}\right\rvert \leqslant \sum\limits_{d=1}^R\frac{1}{d} = \log R + O(1)$, that becomes

$$\lvert A(R)\rvert = \frac{\pi}{4}R^2\sum_{d=1}^R \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} + O(R\log R),\tag{5}$$

and since

$$\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

and

$$\left\lvert \sum_{d=R+1}^\infty \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}\right\rvert \leqslant \sum_{d=R+1}^\infty \frac{1}{d^2} < \frac{1}{R},$$

finally

$$\lvert A(R)\rvert = \frac{3}{2\pi}R^2 + O(R\log R).$$

If we restrict the argument of $A$ and $B$ to be integers, then in $(4)$ the dominant term is

$$\sum_{d=1}^R \mu(d)\biggl\lfloor\frac{R}{d}\biggr\rfloor^2 = \sum_{d=1}^R\mu(d)\biggl(\frac{R}{d}\biggr)^2 - \sum_{d=1}^R \mu(d)\Biggl(\biggl(\frac{R}{d}\biggr)^2 - \biggl\lfloor \frac{R}{d}\biggr\rfloor^2\Biggr),$$

and since

$$\biggl(\frac{R}{d}\biggr)^2 - \biggl\lfloor \frac{R}{d}\biggr\rfloor^2 = \underbrace{\Biggl(\frac{R}{d}-\biggl\lfloor\frac{R}{d}\biggr\rfloor\Biggr)}_{< 1}\underbrace{\Biggl(\frac{R}{d}+\biggl\lfloor\frac{R}{d}\biggr\rfloor\Biggr)}_{\leqslant 2\frac{R}{d}} < 2\frac{R}{d}$$

we see that the asymptotic behaviour doesn't change, only the constant on the second order term changes.

Comment: I like this! Can you fill in some of the details between (4) and (5)?

Comment: Sure. But, I had stupidly assumed that $R$ would always be an integer, now it occurs to me that it probably shouldn't, but any positive real number. In that case, things become easier, since we don't need the floors then. Can you confirm whether $R$ is supposed to be an integer or any positive real number?